# Accessing action arguments in before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there any way to access the arguments of an action method in the before_action that runs?

The @setting variable is being set across the application in a before action in the Application Controller, but the UserMailer class doesn't see to have access to any of the instance variables that are declared in the Application Controller

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

  before_action :set_settings

  def set_settings
    @setting = Setting.find_by(name: test)
  end

  def send_email_1(test)
    @setting...
  end

  def send_email_2(test)
    @setting...
  end

  def send_email_3(test)
    @setting...
  end

  def send_email_4(test)
    @setting...
  end
```

In the set_settings action, I need to access the parameter 'test' that is passed to send_email

Comment: Where is the `test` variable being sent from?

Comment: The UserController using the UserMailer class (`UserMailer.send_email_1("test var")`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, you won't have access to instance variables set in `ApplicationController` when you're inside a mailer action. It's really easy to pass that data in from the controller, however. Here's a simple example:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :load_settings

private

  def load_settings
    @settings = "foo"
  end
end
```

```rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def email
    UserMailer.welcome_message(@settings).deliver_now
  end
end
```

```rb
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def welcome_message(settings)
    @settings = settings
    mail to: "to@example.org"
  end
end
```

The example is a little contrived, but this would make `@settings` available in the mailer view. I tested this locally with a fresh Rails app and it worked as expected.

Comment: This was the path I ended up taking and it works as expected. Thank you!